# Edge Compatibility issues

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have legacy websites (runs well on Chrome, IE, etc)  that  have compatibility problems with Microsoft Edge.  Is there a way to run the website without fixing all the issues in Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround solution.  If you have specific web sites and apps that you know have compatibility problems with Microsoft Edge, for example, your site still use plugins like Java, ActiveX, etc, you can use the Enterprise Mode site list so that the web sites will automatically open using Internet Explorer 11.

Edge and IE 11 are both available on Windows 10, with Edge is the default browser. Using Enterprise Mode means that you can continue to use Microsoft Edge as your default browser, while also ensuring that your apps continue working on IE11.

Additionally, if you know that your intranet sites aren't going to work properly with Microsoft Edge, you can set all intranet sites to automatically open using IE11.

Here is the detail step by step how to do it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270205.aspx

Comment: Nice I didn't know about this :D Too bad it can't be enforced in the website it's header :/ Though we can always add a popup on edge browser users to inform them of course.

Answer (score 0):

Nope Microsoft removed the compatibility mode from edge, IE is still included in windows 10 and that does support compatibility mode.

What problems are you seeing in edge? It might be a lot easier to just fix the problems.